# Windows forms calculator algorithms. Sorting and highest/lowest numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I'm currently working on a calculator but 2 of my algorithms are not working correctly.

1. In my history (listbox) I get the numbers from the calculator and I have a bottom that finds the smallest number. I get an error with my code.
2. I want to have a [sorting] bottom that sorts the numbers ascending or descending. I've tried things as listbox1.sorted but I only get it to work as alphabetic.

If you know what I'm doing wrong with nr.1 or know how to fix a sorting algorithm please let me know.

```
 int count = 0;
 int tal = 0;
 double Mtal = 999999999999999999;
 bool hit;
 int count1 = 0;
 private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (count < 100)
        {
            foreach (var Listboxitem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                hit = false;
                if (Convert.ToDouble(Listboxitem) < Mtal)
                {

                    Mtal = Convert.ToDouble(Listboxitem);
                    hit = true;
                }
                count = count + 1;
                if (hit)
                {
                    count1 = count;
                }
            }
        }
        this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = count1 - 1;

    }
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast? Is the error i get btw

Comment: @EmilSjödin Running the code you have posted here I can't reproduce your issue so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values in ListBox are Integers. So change the declaration of your variable `Mtal` from `double` to `int`. And then, instead of `Convert.ToDouble()` use `int.Parse()`, because you need integers for comparing to existing min value. 
Something like this should work for you:

```
 int count = 0;
 int tal = 0;
 int Mtal = int.MaxValue;
 bool hit;
 int count1 = 0;
 private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     while (count < 100)
     {
          foreach (var Listboxitem in listBox1.Items)
          {
             hit = false;
             if (int.Parse(Listboxitem.ToString()) < Mtal)
             {

                 Mtal = int.Parse(Listboxitem.ToString());
                 hit = true;
             }
             count = count + 1;
             if (hit)
             {
                count1 = count;
             }
        }
    }
    this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = count1 - 1;

 }
```

And then for Ordering I would suggest you to use LINQ on `List<ListItem>`. For your example:

```
private void button_OrderByDescencing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        List<ListItem> items= new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (ListItem a in lb.Items)
        {
            items.Add(a);
        }
        items=items.OrderByDescending(a => int.Parse(a.Value)).ToList();
        foreach (ListItem a in items)
        {
             listBox1.Items.Add(a);
        }

 }
```

And for ascending:

```
 private void button_OrderByAscending_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        List<ListItem> items= new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (ListItem a in lb.Items)
        {
            items.Add(a);
        }
        items= items.OrderBy(a => int.Parse(a.Value)).ToList();
        foreach (ListItem a in items)
        {
             listBox1.Items.Add(a);
        }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer @Tadej 1 problem I get with you code is that it down wanna convert from object to string. (Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string')

Comment: @EmilSjödin See the edit I made. Now both problems should be solved.